# Graphviz Visualizer in WEKA giving empty Grpahs

Tags: weka, graphviz, j48

I was building a J48 tree on the famous iris dataset.

I used weka 3.8 to build the tree.  I also installed graphviz tree visualizer plugin. I use weka in windows 10.

But when I try to visualize it shows me an empty graph. Can some one help me here.

[image: Graphviz Plugin]

[image: Graphviz giving me empty graph]

Comment: Possible 'retrospective duplicate'(!) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782862/graphviz-and-weka-only-generates-empty-trees/45882597 ?