# Graphviz and Weka only generates empty trees

Tags: weka, graphviz

I downloaded Graphviz and installed their package for Weka 3.9, created the props file as indicated on https://github.com/fracpete/graphviz-treevisualize-weka-package with content:

Executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe"
(Tried with and without quotation marks)

And it will only generate empty trees through plugin->visualize tree (Graphviz).

I'm in a bit of stress because I need to deliver a project by this night and discovered an error last moment, can anyone please help? I can deliver without the trees, but theyd be a major help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for bringing this useful Weka plugin to my notice! I think it's written by one of the Weka developers fwiw, not by the authors of Graphviz.

To answer your question, although it's too late for your deadline sorry, are you sure you have created the props file correctly? In particular, the format for specifying the executable path is shown on the project page you linked to as (for example):

```
Executable=C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/dot.exe
```

i.e. with **forward slashes** as the path separator, even on Windows. When I replaced the forward slashes with backslashes it gave me an empty window too, so I suspect this might be your problem.

However, in the absence of the plugin it's quite easy to write the Graphviz code for a decision tree structure by hand from the Weka output, and not too hard to code up a script to convert one to the other. Here's an example:

```
digraph myTree {
Node_1 [label="Predictor1"]
Node_1 -> Node_2 [label="<= 3.14"]
Node_1 -> Node_3 [label="> 3.14"]
Node_2 [label="Class 1", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
Node_3 [label="Predictor2"]
Node_3 -> Node_4 [label="<= 42"]
Node_3 -> Node_5 [label="> 42"]
Node_4 [label="Class 2", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
Node_5 [label="Class 3", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
}
```

and the corresponding output, obtained e.g. from `dot -Tpng -O path\to\myTree.gv`:

[image: tree output from Graphviz]

Comment: Hah, yeah the slashes did definitely do something, thanks for pointing that out, but instead of an empty screen, it now produces.. nothing at all. With larger trees the program hangs for a while, indicating that something is happening, but I am not getting any actual trees.

I no longer need this to work however, so I will not be looking into the issue further myself. Thanks for the answer though, I very much appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but on a Weka/GraphViz install with a new Apple M1 chip. The following worked for me:

1. Install the new version of Homebrew for the Apple M1 chip.
2. Install GraphViz. `brew install graphviz`
3. Open Weka, from the GUI Chooser go to Tools/Package Manager.
4. In the top right corner under 'Unofficial' hit the 'File/URL' button.
5. Copy this address for the install (note, this is a bit hacky as it's the 2014 plugin, if anyone can help get the newer 2018 plugin to install I'd appreciate it but it kept failing for me):  https://github.com/fracpete/graphviz-treevisualize-weka-package/releases/download/v2014.8.1/graphviz-treevisualize-2014.8.1.zip
6. Next you need to find the executable 'dot' file on your computer because you need the correct path to update the props file. If you don't have the correct path, you'll get a white screen in Weka. To find this open Finder and click Go/Go To Folder then type "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz" in the popup window and hit enter. This will open a folder that is typically hidden. Locate the dot file and note the file location.
7. Search your computer for the file ‘GraphVizTreeVisualization.props’ and open it with a text editor.
8. Change the  `Executable=dot` to the correct file location on your computer. For mine it is:
   `Executable=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/9.0.0/bin/dot` and save the file.
9. Copy that file and paste the file here: $[HOME]/wekafiles/props/GraphVizTreeVisualization.props
10. Restart Weka

Note: If you have a Windows machine the procedure should be similar, you'll just be looking for a dot.exe instead of dot file.